# SFTP get failing File "/C:/Users/{username}/downloads/{myVideo.mkv} not found

Tags: shell, ftp, sftp

I am trying to download few files using SFTP.

```
 ls -lrt 
-rw-***** 1 - - 3.3G unveil-movie1-1080p.mkv 
-rw-***** 1 - - 3.3G unveil-movie2=1080p.mkv
```

------- The following get command is failing for me with the following error  -------

```
get unveil-movie1-1080p.mkv 
File "/C:/Users/vashi/downloads/Series.S01.1080p.Bluray.x264-Unveil[rartv]/unveil-movie1-1080p.mkv" not found.
```

However if I do a recursive copy then I am able to download the files

```
 cd ..
 get -r Series.S01.1080p.Bluray.x264-Unveil[rartv]
```

I'm transferring files from one Windows system to another.
What did I miss?

And also the file permissions are 777 in my remote machine but the sftp listing shows rw-*****

I can download the directory but not individual files; I know we should be able to download individual files if the directory download is available; I'm not sure what I missed; any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to include local_file where you want to save the downloaded files on your local machine Although this is optional

Example:

```
sftp> get /path/to/remote/file.txt /path/to/local/file.txt
```

In your problem

```
get unveil-movie1-1080p.mkv  unveil-movie1-1080p.mkv
```

if a filename contains special characters you can try using to escape using a double  quote

```
sftp> get "/path/to/remote/file.txt" "/path/to/local/file.txt"
```

Comment: _Hi Akshay, Thanks for the reply. I found the issue my parent folder had special characters in the path name._

**Folder name: Series.S01.1080p.Bluray.x264-Unveil[rartv].**

I have specified the absolute path in the get command that worked for me


**get "C:/Users/{username}/downloads/Series.S01.1080p.Bluray.x264-Unveil[rartv]/unveil-movie1-1080p"**
_As you suggested, if the path to the file has any special characters, we need to escape them using ". 
So, I have to change the directory name or give an absolute path in double quotes._